# Unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am somewhat new to the Linux system so I would appreciate any help here. Maybe I am overlooking something easy. I am for looping through some variables, and I keep getting this error when executing

```
 line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11'
 line 8: `20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni11Nj01'
```

Here is the loop that is getting stuck.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
#
for s1 in new new1
do
for s2 in 20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj00 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11
20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni11Nj01
20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni11Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10
do
```

I've used similar files like this, and they have all worked fine. (As well as changing the mode of the file).

Comment: Looks like you may have newline character  (rather than a space) separating some of the items you are iterating over in your second for loop.

Comment: It seems you have not discovered the beauty of [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) yet? Just paste your script there and it will give you a line-by-line of problems (which you can fix in real-time until no more problems remain)

Answer (score 1):

As presented here the `for s2` line is broken across 3 lines leaving the string `20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11` (from the error message) sitting on a line all by itself and since the parser is looking for a `do` (following the `for s2 ...` line) you get the error message re: *`unexpected token`* (ie, `20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11` != `do`).

A couple options ...

Add a continuation character (`\`) on the end of the first 2 lines, eg:

```
for s2 in 20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj00 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 \
20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni11Nj01 \
20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni11Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10
do
```

Or you can pull all of those strings/names up into the main line, eg:

```
for s2 in 20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj00 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni10Nj11 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni00Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni11Nj01 20_0_200-75-20_0_200.Ni11Nj10 20_0_200-80-20_0_200.Ni10Nj10
do
```

That should get you past the current issue.  If you run into any other issues and have problems resolving consider cutting-n-pasting your code (along with shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/); this does a pretty good job of picking up on common coding/syntax issues.

---

Another possible issue you'll want to review ... you've tagged the question `bash` but your shebang (`/bin/sh`) suggests you may not be using `bash` (ie, `sh` is not the same as `bash`); while it's possible your system has redefined `/bin/sh` as a symlink to, or copy of, `bash` that's not very common; you'll want to verify which shell you're using as this will dictate the syntax of some commands in future code you write.